# Formation of carbocation on reaction with strong acid in presence of halogen

Tags: halides

[image: Doubt question]
Shouldn't the carbocation be formed away from the -I effect of the Cl atom for more stability. Backbonding is achieved in a later step after hydride shift.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would result in a primary carbocation. Due to substituent groups stabilizing the carbocation's empty p-orbital in what's known as hyperconjugation, primary carbocations are less stable than secondary.
Here are some heats of formation from the  [Active Thermochemical Tables (version 1.130)](https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.130/index.php):

*t*-Butylium (tertiary carbocation): 710.72 $\pm$ 0.98 kJ/mol

*sec*-Butylium (secondary carbocation): 769.0 $\pm$ 1.6 kJ/mol

*n*-Butylium (primary carbocation): 803.1 $\pm$ 1.2 kJ/mol

While tertiary carbocations are more stable than secondary ones, an electron-withdrawing group such as a chloro group destabilizes the carbocation.

Comment: Right. So basically we can say that here we get more number of alpha H so more hyper conjugation hence, inspire of greater -I, carbocation will be formed there due to compensation by hyper conjugation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hyperconjugation stabilizes the carbocation by electron donating groups (with p orbitals) adjacent to the empty p orbital of the positive formal charge carbon, not the destabilizing effect of alpha hydrogens.